# How to get the attribute "value" from the array

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I am trying to get the attribute "value" from my array in the xml file. This is my array:

```
<resources>

    <string-array name="myArray">
        <item name="item1" value="www.something.com" type="urls">first url</item>
        <item name="item2" value="www.somethingelse.com" type="urls">second url</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

and basically I have a listview that should only display the name of the web page and in the intent, they will be redirected to the website. I am trying to get the value into a string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou.

Comment: Seems like Android ignores the attributes in `<item>`. I think you have to manually read the file and parse the XML.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: After some consideration, I don't think you need the attributes. I posted the alternative solution.

Comment: The thing is I do not want to show trhe urls in the listview, just the name of the websites. Would I need some sort of parser?

Comment: I see. I suggest to use 2 arrays instead; one for the URLs and the other for the names of the website. Might sound not efficient, but definitely easier and simpler than trying to implement XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Based from your requirement, you can do it like this instead of reading the resource and read the file content manually/implementing the XML parser.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="array_url">
        <item>www.something.com</item>
        <item>www.somethingelse.com</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
<resources>
    <string-array name="array_name">
        <item>first url</item>
        <item>second url</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then get the array with

```
String[] urls= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_url);
String[] names= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_name);
```

Use `names` for the list, and when it's clicked, you can get the item position, read the URL from `urls`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] websites = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
String[] temp = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

Comment: that gets "first url"? I would like to get value="www.somnething.com". How can I achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
String[] classes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```